Calculating change to radio signal propagating around via satellite orbits
What is the best way to calculate either the time difference or frequency change for a radio signal in the following scenario?
60 satellites are in the same circular orbital path at 6 degree intervals. The satellites are configured so that when they receive a signal from either nearest neighbor (retrograde or prograde) they reflect or pass-it-on without modification to the neighbor on the other (prograde or retrograde, respectively).
So, the signal propagates in both directions all the way around and back to the originating satellite.

When the originating satellite receives both versions of the signal after they have been propagated around the orbit, are they received at exactly the same time, and, if not, then how do I calculate the delay between them?
Do both signals arrive at the same original frequency, and if not, how do I calculate the change?

I expect the sizes of the differences (if there are any) depends on the size of the orbit, the velocity of the satellites, and the delay caused by reflection.
Maybe I am also missing another variable?

Can you supply a sketch of how this "reflection" works? Just for the first three satellites or so on one side is fine.

Frequency shift will only occur if there is a velocity difference between emitter and receiver, as in Doppler shift. If the emitter and receiver are the same satellite, there will be no shift. In any given period, the same number of pulses will be emitted and received. This is true for circular orbits. Not sure about non-circular orbits.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect

The Sagnac effect appears to be the effect I am trying (poorly) to describe. The page referenced by John Doty does seem to have the information I was seeking. Thank you.

Answer:

According to Uncle Albert, the speed of light “c” will always be measured the same in an inertial frame of reference. So both the prograde and retrograde signals will travel at the same velocity if measured in the inertial framework of the Earth. In the time taken for the signals to circle the earth, the “mothership” satellite will have advanced in its orbit, lengthening the prograde path and shortening the retrograde path by identical amounts.

The circumference of your 60-sided polygon divided by c will give a good approximation of the arrival time of the signals.  Standard orbital mechanics equations will give the velocity of the mothership. The arrival time difference can then be calculated.

Both signals will have the same measured frequency upon arrival as when they were transmitted. The prograde signal was blueshifted, as measured in the Earth’s inertial reference frame, when it was transmitted. But it will be redshifted by the same amount on its arrival. Other way around for the retrograde transmission.

Frequency shift will only occur if there is a velocity difference between emitter and receiver, as in Doppler shift. If the emitter and receiver are the same satellite, there will be no shift. In any given period, the same number of pulses will be emitted and received.
